# Changing the eyes camera's direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

We are trying to get the experience like you were an animal. And animals have different eye positions and rotations.

We wanted to use google cardboard because it's the most accessible for us as a preview.

But the question is, is there a way to change the angle of the eye cameras in the google vr SDK?

Thanks in advance,

Olivierus

Comment: I don't think so, no. I suspect that doing so would be very disorienting, which is why it isn't supported.

Comment: Well, we are an art school, so we have to try and see if we can make an experience out of it. If you have an idea please share if possible.

Comment: The only time that I know of where it was possible to do that was in the early days of the Oculus, with the DK1. At the time the Unity plugin side used two actual camera objects (that you didn't mess with, but could). But the plugin no longer looks like that and the XR output is handled automatically.

Comment: Okay, thanks I will look into this.

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/34680/gearvr-separate-cameras-for-each-eye-in-unity3d) since this is from 2016 it might however be the old version Draco18s was talking about

Comment: Thank you derHugo, I will be investigating this in a second